# Как сделать что бы пользователь в пайтоне вводил числа списком?

Tags: python

Как сделать что бы пользователь в пайтоне вводил числа списком?

Comment: Каким именно списком? Уточните вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var1, var2 = input().split()
```

Comment: Только потом нужно будет к типу привести

Comment: Сломается на, например, "23, 21"